# How to change female and male to True and False in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I know this is a basic question and I am a beginner, but I've tried a ton of methods and none of them work in my case, so here I go:

How to change the values female and male in a column named sex to True and False in Python Pandas. None of the codes below have helped:

```py
#change the binary variables to True and False
data2['sex'] = data2['sex'] == 'female'  

#change the binary variables to True and False
data.replace({'C2': {'X': True, 'Y': False}})

#df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['female', 'male']})
#df

#d = {'female': True, 'male': False}
#df['sex'].map(d)

#pd.get_dummies(data2[['sex']]).head()
#data2 = pd.get_dummies(data2, columns=['sex'], prefix=['sex'], drop_first=True)
```

Comment: You should provide copy-pasteable data for people to mess with. Did you try using `df.apply()`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're really going for, but it seems like an X-Y problem.

```py
def gender(string):
    return string == 'female'
```

Comment: To make this answer more complete: `df["sex"] = df["sex"].apply(gender)` I believe. Don't really feel like making my own test dataframe to confirm.

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not change the values of the column sex: female and male to true and false

Comment: @ela3 see my comment for the complete answer. You really should put in a little more effort than simply copy-pasting people's answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am really trying to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a replace function. It will change your data only when you set 'inplace' parameter as 'True':

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['female', 'male']})
df.replace({'sex': {'female': True, 'male': False}}, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
      sex
0    True
1   False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the apply method with a custom function

```py
def sex_change(x):
    change= None
    if x == 'female':
        change= True
    else:
        change= False
    return change

# or

def sex_change(x):
    if x == 'female':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now use the apply method on your dataframe

```py
df['sex']= df['sex'].apply(sex_change)
```

Comment: You should learn how to properly format code.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!! <3

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method:

```
df2= df['sex'] == 'female'
df['sex'] = df2.values
```

or in one line

```
df['sex'] = (df['sex'] == 'female').values
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change it with

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['sex'] = df['sex'].map({'Female': 0, 'Male': 1})
```